# Why can document.body be referenced directly but other elements can't?

Tags: javascript, dom

If I had a markup like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="file.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a header</h1>
    <div id='container'>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and a JavaScript file associated with it like this:

```
const newButton = document.createElement('button');
newButton.innerText='Hey!';
document.getElementById('container').appendChild('newButton');
```

Why do I need to fetch div by either it's Id or by a referencing it to a variable via querySelector(), but I can simply reference body by something like:

```
document.body.appendChild('newButton');
```

Comment: Because that's the structure of the `document` object. It has `head` and `body` properties that contain those components of the DOM.

Comment: FYI, you can use `window.container`.

Comment: No components apart from `head` and `body` *necessarily* exist within an `html` component. This is why these special elements can be referenced directly

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean @Gershy , or link relevant docs ?

Comment: there can be *multiple* div, p, span, h2, h3, ul, li etc. tags in a document, but there can only be *one*  body, that's why.